# pybind with boost/dll - dual use DLL?

Tags: python, c++, boost, dll, pybind11

#### TL;DR

Adding pybind11 bindings to a working C++ DLL project allows me to import and use the resulting DLL in Python but  breaks my ability to use it in C++ code using boost/dll machinery.

#### Summary

I've got a C++ library that I compile to `FooLib.dll`. I use [boost/dll](https://github.com/boostorg/dll)'s `BOOST_DLL_ALIAS` and `boost::dll::import_alias()` to export and load a class `Foo` that does some work in other C++ code.

Some details omitted but it all works great, following this [recipe](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_dll/tutorial.html#boost_dll.tutorial.factory_method_in_plugin).

I'd like to be able to call the same library code from Python to do some complicated functional testing and do comparisons to `numpy/scipy` prototypes without having to write so much test code in C++.

So I tried to add [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) bindings to the `FooLib` DLL project using `PYBIND11_MODULE`.

It compiles, I get a `FooLib.dll`. I can copy and rename that to `FooLib.pyd`, import it as a Python module, and it all works fine. I export `Foo` as a Python class, and it works.

However, when I compile in the pybind bindings, the boost/dll import machinery can no longer load the original `FooLib.dll`. I verify with `boost::dll::library_info()` that the appropriate `CreateFoo` symbol is exported to the DLL. But loading with `boost::dll::import_alias()` fails with:

```
boost::dll::shared_library::load() failed: The specified module could not be found
```

#### Minimal Example

Unfortunately, something that needs a C++ and Python executable and compiled boost isn't exactly minimal, but I did my best here:

https://github.com/danzimmerman/pybind-boostdll-minimal

Direct links to the source files:

#### DLL Project Files

[`HelloSayerLib.h`](https://github.com/danzimmerman/pybind-boostdll-minimal/blob/master/source/HelloSayerLib.h)

[`HelloSayerImp.cpp`](https://github.com/danzimmerman/pybind-boostdll-minimal/blob/master/source/HelloSayerImp.cpp)

#### C++ Test Code

[`HelloSayerLibCppTest.cpp`](https://github.com/danzimmerman/pybind-boostdll-minimal/blob/master/source/HelloSayerLibCppTest.cpp)

#### Python Test Code

[`HelloSayerLibPythonTests.py`](https://github.com/danzimmerman/pybind-boostdll-minimal/blob/master/source/HelloSayerLibPythonTests.py)

Any advice for next steps?

Is it even possible to compile to one binary that works for both C++ and Python like this?

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but what got my attention - when you inspect the library, you specify the path like this: boost::dll::library_info libinfo(libDir / "HelloSayerLib.dll"); - notice the dll at the end. But when you import an alias, you do it like this: hscreator = boost::dll::import_alias<hs_create_function_t>(libFile, ... where libFile is defined as follows: boost::filesystem::path libFile = libDir / "HelloSayerLib"; (no dll at the end). You sure it does not matter? Edit: okay, nevermind - I forgot it works without python bindings...sorry

Comment: Only suggestion which comes to my mind - clone boost library from github, checkout your desired version, build it in DEBUG, link it to your application (built in debug as well) and execute boost::dll::import_alias<hs_create_function_t> step by step.

Comment: Thanks Marek. I don't think it should matter, since `boost::dll::import_alias()` is called with `boost::dll::load_mode::append_decorations` which as I understand it appends `.dll` on Windows, `.so` on Linux, `.dylib` on Mac or something like that, but I don't think that flag works with `library_info()`. There's a `boost::dll::shared_library::suffix()` function that I think I can use to remove the hardcoded `.dll`. Trying now to be sure this isn't related. Good point about debug build, I'm new to C++ debugging and forget about it.

Comment: And I'm sure you know a possible workaround in case you are in hurry - create a separate target for the class itself and then link it with target containing boost bindings and another one containing only python bindings. But you'd end up with two DLLs, which does not answer the question.

Comment: A module built with pybind links against Python DLLs and needs to have them available at run time. Basically you need them in your path.

Comment: Thanks @n. 'pronouns' m. that was definitely the problem. Making the python DLL available does indeed allow the C++ program to run. Do you want to post an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion in @n.'pronouns'm. comment is correct. Simply copying the python DLL from the Anaconda distribution I built against to the C++ program's run directory fixes the problem. Makes sense in retrospect, but didn't occur to me.

Makes it even more likely that I should keep the builds separate or at least set up my real project to only build with pybind bindings on my machine.